# Why was PyPI called the cheese shop?

Tags: python, pypi

I was running through the tutorials to build a Python distro package yesterday and the PyPI site kept on being calling the Cheese Shop. Why is that?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Following the fact that the name of the Python language is taken from the Monty Python comedy group, it's a reference to the "[Cheese Shop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hz1JWzyvv8A)" sketch they did.

In the sketch, a customer becomes frustrated because the cheese shop apparently does not have very many kinds of cheese available. Similarly, the package index PyPI did not have many packages available originally.

There have been other prominent Python projects that have used the same approach to select names ([Bicycle Repairman](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BicycleRepairMan) and [Grail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grail_%28web_browser%29) are the first that come to mind)

Comment: http://docs.python.org/faq/general.html#do-i-have-to-like-monty-python-s-flying-circus

Comment: A neural simulator came up with 'Brian' - an anagram of... oh you get it!