# Wheel is a reference to the other Python

Tags: python, python-wheel

[PEP 427](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/) describes the move to [.whl files](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/) from .egg for Python packaging.

In the [comparisons section](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#comparison-to-egg) of the PEP, there is point 6:

> Wheel is a reference to the other Python.

I don't understand this point, what are they trying to say?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.egg` is a reference to the snake variety of python, `.whl` is a reference to Monty Python's "wheel of cheese"

Comment: @NPE: That's my best guess

Comment: Aha.  Well I guess that will fit in nicely with the [PyPi cheeseshop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5393986/674039).

Comment: Also see the 'slogans' section of an [old revision of the `wheel` package documentation (< 2017-10-01)](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/blob/3c7b6a0d13ee036ea8f6488ab4ecddd9826c00db/docs/index.rst#slogans)

Comment: Now it occurs to me, are you sure `.egg` is a reference to the python snake, and not to spam, spam, spam and eggs?

Comment: What do you mean with snake variety?

Comment: @Private: "Python", the word, can refer to either the Python [snake species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(genus)) or [Monty Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python) comedy group. So "snake variety of python" simply means "python the snake, not Monty Python"